# How to align the derivation of equation?

Tags: equations, alignment

The derivation of equation is given below. Can anyone suggest on how to align the equations in such a way that all the equations get covered under same equation number?

```
\begin{multline}\label{eqn-5.9}
s_{p_m}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk(\phi_{i_m}-(2\pi p_m/P_m))}\\
=\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk\phi_{i_m}-jk2\pi p_m/P_m)}\\
=\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{-j(2\pi k p_m/P_m)}\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}e^{jk\phi_{i_m}}
\end{multline}
```

The current output obtained is as follows.

[image: MWC]

Comment: Use `\sum` instead of `\Sigma` in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use `align`. Use `split` also if you want to have the numbering centered and the label is for the whole equation (I don't recommend it though). And, you have `\sum` for sums, no need to use `\Sigma`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
s_{p_m}&=\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk(\phi_{i_m}-(2\pi p_m/P_m))}\nonumber\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk\phi_{i_m}-jk2\pi p_m/P_m)}\nonumber\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{-j(2\pi k p_m/P_m)}\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}e^{jk\phi_{i_m}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or smaller sum (with in-line style) if you like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
s_{p_m}&=\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk(\phi_{i_m}-(2\pi p_m/P_m))}\nonumber\\
&=\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk\phi_{i_m}-jk2\pi p_m/P_m)}\nonumber\\
&=\textstyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{-j(2\pi k p_m/P_m)}\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}e^{jk\phi_{i_m}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

one more possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eqn-5.9}
\begin{split}
s_{p_m}
    & = \sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
        f_k\exp\Bigl(jk(\phi_{i_m}-\mfrac{2\pi p_m}{P_m}\Bigr) \\
    & = \sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
        f_k\exp\Bigl(jk\phi_{i_m} - \mfrac{jk2\pi p_m}{P_m}\Bigr)\\
    & = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k\exp\Bigl(-j\mfrac{2\pi k p_m}{P_m}\Bigr)
        \sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\exp\Bigl(jk\phi_{i_m}\Bigr)
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you would like to have it. I prefer to have the equation number on the last row:

```
\begin{align}
  s_{p_m}&=\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk(\phi_{i_m}-(2\pi p_m/P_m))}\nonumber\\
  &=\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk\phi_{i_m}-jk2\pi p_m/P_m)}\nonumber\\
  &=\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{-j(2\pi k p_m/P_m)}\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}e^{jk\phi_{i_m}}
  \label{eqn-5.9}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is one of these that you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn-5.9}
\begin{aligned}
s_{p_m} & =\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk(\phi_{i_m}-(2\pi p_m/P_m))}\\
 & =\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk\phi_{i_m}-jk2\pi p_m/P_m)}\\
 & =\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{-j(2\pi k p_m/P_m)}\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}e^{jk\phi_{i_m}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
s_{p_m} =\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk(\phi_{i_m}-(2\pi p_m/P_m))}\\
  =\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{jk\phi_{i_m}-jk2\pi p_m/P_m)}\\
  =\Sigma_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{-j(2\pi k p_m/P_m)}\Sigma_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_{i_m}e^{jk\phi_{i_m}}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]